# react-i18next fallback backend combination issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internationalization, i18next, react-i18next

I've used "i18next-chained-backend" library to load multiple i18n backend but it seems it does not work as my expectation. I expect that it will load multiple resources from those backends, then when I translate some key, it checks that key on those backends one by one in order.

Currently, I think when the first backend is loaded successfully, it will use that backend and ignore the rest. How can I achieve as my expect? I appreciate any helps, thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you solve this issue? Could you please share your code or your findings for this?

Comment: I'm using the different namespace name for those backend.

Comment: Thanks for answering! However for me it's not quite clear what you exactly mean by that. As far as I understand, when I load multiple chained backends, only the first one is taken - doesn't matter if the second backend has an additional namespace that the first one doesn't have.

Comment: @RaideR I've posted my answer below, hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my setup to resolve the multiple backends issues:

For example I have 2 backend called: backend1 (1st priority), backend2.
On backend1, I create namespace1 then make namespace1 as default namespace.
On backend2, I create namespace2 then make namespace2 as fallback namespace.
So in namespace1 (backend1) I have

```
{
   "key1": "different Key1"
}
```

and in namespace2 (backend2) I have

```
{
   "key1": "Key1",
   "key2": "Key2"
}
```

So here is the result:
t("key1") will be "different Key1" --> Because it's found in namespace1 as default (as it's 1st priority)
t("key2") will be "Key2"  --> Because it's not found in namespace1 so it will look at the fallback namespace (namespace2).

Comment: Thanks for the update - very much appreciated. You are still using i18next-chained-backend - right? Could you share your initialization please? I cant get it to work - it always seems like ChainedBackend only considers the first backend that its able to load

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine. I had a problem with an external plugin. Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: Yes, no problem, we need to set up 2 namespace (1st for defaultNS, 2nd for fallbackNS) to make it load from both namespace to find a translation key

Answer (score 1):

To do so you may need to create your own i18next backend plugin: https://www.i18next.com/misc/creating-own-plugins

Comment: maybe this helps too: https://www.i18next.com/how-to/backend-fallback

Answer (score -1):

If anyone stumbles upon this and is using phrase.com, [following their tutorial](https://help.phrase.com/help/react-native-sdk-installation-instructions) - you have to adjust the corresponding code for loading the phrase backend. Without the adjustment the resourcesToBackend function would overwrite your `localTranslation`.

```
const localResources = {
  'en-US': {
     localTranslation: translationEN,
   },
};
...
const backendPhrase = resourcesToBackend((language, namespace, callback) => {
  if (namespace === 'localTranslation') {
    // we don't want to let phrase.com overwrite the localTranslation
    callback(null, null);
    return;
  }

   phrase
    .requestTranslation(language)
    .then((remoteResources) => {
      callback(null, remoteResources);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      callback(error, null);
    });
```

Later on when initializing your i18n instance - configure the namespaces accordingly:

```
...
ns: ['localTranslation', 'translation'],
defaultNS: 'translation',
fallbackNS: 'localTranslation',
...
```